# 'How to acccess data property inside setup in vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to access data property inside setup() in vue 3 but is giving me this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$localStorage' of undefined
```

`data()`

```
  data() {
    return {
      $localStorage: {},

}
```

setup

```
  setup() {
   this.$localStorage
}
```

How i can access this property inside setup()?

Comment: Inside `setup()`, `this` won't be a reference to the current active instance Since `setup()` is called before other component options are resolved, `this` inside `setup()` will behave quite differently from `this` in other options. This might cause confusions when using `setup()` along other Options API. Please refer this for more details https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#arguments

Comment: Can you also explain your use case?

Comment: as far as I know "this" isn't other options it is literally bound to undefined according to the Types in Vue.

Answer (score 7):

One solution would be importing `getCurrentInstance` from vue and use it in onMounted lifecycle or in a consumable:

```
import { onMounted, getCurrentInstance } from "vue";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      key: "test",
    };
  },
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(getCurrentInstance().data.key);
    });
  },
};
```

However, this usage is highly discouraged as stated in [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance).

Instead you could define that data property in setup using ref or reactive like this:

```
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    const $localStorage = ref({});
  },
};
```

or

```
import { reactive } from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    const $localStorage = reactive({});
  },
};
```

These solutions will work if your data and setup function will be in the same component.

If you are trying to access to a child component, you can use `ref` for accomplishing this task. More detailed information about `ref` is [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to return the property from the setup method, if not using

```
<script setup></script>
```

as stated in the [Official Documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs)

```
<script>
import {ref} from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Demo",
  data: () => ({
    $localStorage: {}
  }),
  setup() {
    // make it reactive
    const $localStorage = ref({})
    
    // Finally return the property
    return {$localStorage}
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).